# Cannot set nivo pie chart color scheme

Tags: reactjs, charts

I integrated the [nivo library](https://nivo.rocks/). I managed to get this pie chart to work:

[image]

For this, I used this slightly modified code from the example:

```js
<ResponsivePie
  data={data}
  margin={config.margins}
  padding={0.3}
  colors="nivo"
  borderColor="inherit:darker(1.6)"
  animate
  motionStiffness={90}
  motionDamping={15}
  legends={config.legends}
  sortByValue
  innerRadius={0}
  padAngle={0}
  cornerRadius={0}
  borderWidth={0}
  radialLabelsSkipAngle={10}
  radialLabelsTextXOffset={6}
  radialLabelsTextColor="#333333"
  radialLabelsLinkOffset={0}
  radialLabelsLinkDiagonalLength={16}
  radialLabelsLinkHorizontalLength={24}
  radialLabelsLinkStrokeWidth={1}
  radialLabelsLinkColor="#CCCCCC"
  slicesLabelsSkipAngle={10}
  slicesLabelsTextColor="#333333"
/>
```

Now, I wanted the colors to be a grayscale, so I changed the `colors` prop to "greys", as shown in their docs:

```
colors={{ scheme: 'greys' }}
```

This results in:

[image]

I also tried:

```
colors="greys"
```

Using `"greens"` also results in the same.

If you want to try it out:
[image: Open in CodeSandbox]

What do I need to do?

Comment: Not familiar with nivo but the docs says that it's the right syntax. Can you create a codesandbox?

Comment: @MoshFeu check the updated post.

Answer (score 2):

I see that this is an old question, but I recently encountered the same issue when integrating with nivo. However I did find a solution so I decided to share it anyway.

After playing around with it I found that the code provided in the interactive view is not valid in React, if you would like to use a theme you should use the following syntax:

```
colors={"nivo"} // or the name of the theme you picked
```

instead of:

```
colors={{ scheme: 'nivo' }}
```

PS: If you want to use some of the other themes you might need to supply them additionally since just a couple of them come with nivo by default.

Comment: It's so old that I can't check whether this works, but thanks anyway for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 0):

The property name is not colors, it's color:

```
color={{ scheme: "nvio" }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).